# Revolution Sliders Not Showing UP

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, revolution-slider

I recently updated to Rev Slider 5.0 and now my old slider's aren't showing up, nor are any new sliders.

I emailed them, but they just sent me to generic support.  I have tried all the normal troubleshooting of Global Settings changes, and tried turning off and on all other plugins.  Other than turning off and on my theme, I am at a loss.  Likely a JS issue.  How do I downgrade back to the last version?  I have the zip file, but when I try to upload it it says it is not a valid file.

I am afraid to remove the rev Slider plugin from my plugin file for fear of losing hours and hours and hours of work on my sliders.

Any suggestions?

Comment: posting any kind of code sample will be appreciated

Comment: There is a quickfix update  5.0.4.1 that works if you updated your wordpress to wp 4.3. There was some kind of a bug in the rev slider that made it not appear. Update your slider.

Comment: If you bought the theme with a bundled rev slider, you cant update until you buy a standalone rev slider. Useless.